# Constructing 6-fold cover of $S^1 \vee S^1$ with deck transformation group $\cong S_6$

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

So i'm thinking that this will be a cover space of maximum possible symmetry. Will a "necklace" of 6 circles work? Any tips appreciated

Comment: I don't know the answer immediately, but I don't think it's a necklace of $6$ circles. I think it's much bigger. The point is that the deck group acts freely, so the inverse image of a point must contain more than $6$ elements.  In fact, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem (since the stabilizer must be trivial), the orbit must contain $|S_6| = 6! = 720$ elements.  So you are looking for at least a 720-sheeted covering....(or I made a mistake.  I usually just think about the deck group associated to the universal covering...)

Comment: Supposing the cover is connected, it is impossible to have a 6 sheeted cover like that because the number of elements in the preimage is the index of the fundamental group under the induced map (call the image G). You might know that the deck transformations of a covering are isomorphic to the normalizer of G quotient G. This implies that index is at least 720.

Comment: Probably a better explanation (but in the same vein) is that a deck transformation is determined by where it sends a single point, so an n sheeted cover has at most n deck transformations.

Comment: Are you sure about that? What if $p: Y \rightarrow X$ and $x \in X$ s.t. $x$ lifts to $y_1, y_2, y_3$. Isn't it possible to have a deck transformation that takes $y_2$ to $y_3$ whilst fixing $y_1$? And surely in the group of deck transformations this would not be the same as the element that fixes each $y_i$

Comment: It is a consequence of the lifting properties for covers. I think Hatcher proves it.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about connectivity. If your cover is not required to be connected then you can take $6$ copies of $S^1 \vee S^1$ and the deck transformation group just permutes the copies.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct that this construction is impossible, however the reason is flawed.

First of all, the action of the deck transformation group $G$ of a connected covering map $f : X \to Y$ a *free* action, meaning that the action of a nontrivial element of $G$ has no fixed points --- so no, a deck transformation cannot take $y_2$ to $y_3$ whilst fixing $y_1$.

Second, given $x \in X$ and $y=f(x) \in Y$, the action of $G$ on the subset $f^{-1}(y) \subset X$ need not be transitive. In fact, that action is transitive if and only if the covering map $f : X \to Y$ is regular, if and only if the image of the induced homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1(Y,f(x))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(Y,f(x))$. However, this only makes the construction *more* impossible (if that means anything), because it implies that the cardinality of $f^{-1}(x)$ is greater than or equal to the order of the group $G$.

So, in a covering map of degree $6$, the set $f^{-1}(x)$ has cardinality $6$, and there is no free action of a group of order $6! = 120$ on a set of cardinality $6$.

For proofs of the various things discussed in this answer, I suggest sitting down with a good solid course on the relationship between fundamental groups and covering spaces, as in Hatcher.

Answer (score 0):

There is a $6!$-fold connected normal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ with deck transformation group $S_6$.  Recall that $S_6$ has a presentation with two generators, hence there is a normal subgroup $N\subset F_2$ of the free group on two generators.  Let's identify $F_2=\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$.  Hence, there is a homomorphism $f:\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)\to S_6$ through the quotient map $F_2\to F_2/N$.

By standard facts about covering spaces (as seen in Hatcher) there is then a connected normal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ associated to the normal subgroup $N$ for which $S_6$ is the group of deck transformations.

You might know this covering space as the *Cayley graph* of $S_6$ with the chosen generating set.  In fact, the two-generator Cayley graphs of $S_6$ encompass the set of all connected normal covers of $S^1\vee S^1$ with deck transformation group isomorphic to $S_6$.

(William in the comments points out that there is a $6$-fold *disconnected* cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ with $S_6$ as its group of deck transformations: the disjoint union $\coprod_{i=1}^6S^1\vee S^1$.)